# Simple countdown - onClick button fires on render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a very simple 5 second countdown in React and can't seem to get it to work. In the code below, the timer starts as soon as the app renders for the first time, and then once it gets past 0 it seems to flicker and break down.

Any suggestions?

```js
import './styles/App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
    
  const [ time, setTime ] = useState(5);

  const startCountdown = setInterval(() => {
      if (time < 0 ) {
        clearInterval(startCountdown);
      }
      setTime(time - 1);
  }, 1000);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{time}</h1>
      <button onClick={startCountdown}>Start</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You didn’t assign any function to onClick. setInterval calls immediately and returns timer id. Wrapping setInterval in function resolves your issue

Comment: you might wanna add `time <= 0` too (unless you're handling negative time, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it as a function. Currently your assigning this as code block which will be executed straightway.
exp:

```
const startCountdown = () => setInterval(() => {
      if (time < 0 ) {
        clearInterval(startCountdown);
      }
      setTime(time - 1);
  }, 1000);
```